# Microsoft.Graph.createLink: 400 Version not specified

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm trying to create a sharing link for OneDrive item using [Microsoft.Graph.CreateLink action](https://graph.microsoft.io/GraphDocuments/en-us/api-reference/beta/api/item_createlink.htm):

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/01B642VZR4QM6MX36HGZELNLHCFGY26JJ6/Microsoft.Graph.createLink HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer {access_token}
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "type":"edit"
}
```

and I got the following error:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "Version not specified.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "3ca90464-3910-49e1-92f2-3a9daa822944",
            "date": "2016-02-17T15:56:16"
        }
    }
}
```

Either method description or [metadata](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata) does not contain any information about versions needed other than in the API endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

From logs corresponding to request-id:3ca90464-3910-49e1-92f2-3a9daa822944, the request received by the service was "POST https://graph.microsoft.com/". The lack of path segment in the request URL is causing this expected error. Can you please check the request again?

Comment: That's because my HTTP client received header `Location: https://graph.microsoft.com` and treated it as a redirect command. Thanks!